# Salesforce: trigger on related list

Tags: triggers, salesforce

Suppose I have two objects 
     1.Account- standard object[it has a field name Status_*c which is a picklist having value inprogress and closed]

     2.Client*_c - custom object[it also have same field name Status__c which is a picklist having value inprogress and closed]

and Client__c has lookup to Account name which means Account has a related list of client object .

My question is :
    I want to write a trigger where if I put account status to "closed"  I can not put client status to "closed",it should throw an error message on client object or if I put client status to closed I can not put account status to closed vice versa.

Can any one please help me to write a trigger on this??

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, I think what you are looking to do is set up Validation Rules on both of those objects. Your validation rule on Client_*c should be pretty simple: TEXT(Status*_c) == 'Closed' && TEXT(Account_*c.Status*_c) == 'Closed'

The more interesting piece is how you handle making sure none of your related items are Closed when you move the Account to Closed. I tend to prefer creating a field on the Account that keeps track of the status of the related items (checkbox) that basically tells me whether it is valid for me to change my status or not. In this case, the validation rule becomes pretty simple. In order to set that boolean value, I end up using a Trigger on Client__c that basically just grabs all the Accounts when a Client is being modified in the batch (taking into account both inserts, upserts, and deletes):

```
SELECT Account__c.Id FROM Client__c WHERE Id =: Trigger.new OR Id =: Trigger.old
```

Then create a Set of all the Account Ids (in this example, named accounts), and run a query to retrieve ALL Clients related to those Ids (in a single query to ensure you don't hit SOQL limits).

```
SELECT Account__c.Id, Status__c FROM Client__c WHERE Account__c.Id =: accounts
```

From the results of this, you will iterate over all of the entries, tossing them into a Map keyed by the Account Id where the value is a List of Clients. When you are done, run a query to get all accounts based on the "accounts" list from earlier (which was just a list of strings, not actual Accounts), subsequently iterate over all the Clients associated with that Account, and if a Client is marked as Closed, you will update the metadata of that Account accordingly. If no Clients are closed, the Account will be marked as such. Once you are finished, run an update statement to update the list of Accounts that you have modified.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ...i can use roll up summery and validation rules to fulfill the above requirement but i want to use trigger in this case.

Comment: If you purely want the logic in a trigger, you can programmatically add errors to fields http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm